# Python try-except Name Error

Tags: python, animation, error-handling

I am making a clock type program in Python which has the option for formatting. I've got a function where the background colour is assigned by a variable, but I want to make the program user-friendly. When the variable for the bg colour is a string like "black", it returns this:

```
      File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 1105, in _colorstr
        raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color string: %s" % str(color))
    TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: black
```

And so I added the try except code which is meant to catch the TurtleGraphicsError error. However, when I run the code, this happens:

```
    except (TurtleGraphicsError):
NameError: name 'TurtleGraphicsError' is not defined
```

I've tried with and without brackets. Any idea why this is happening?

Python 2.7.12, Windows 8.1
Used imports are:

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import day_name
from time import sleep
import turtle
import os
```

Comment: Can we see your imports. Sometimes you need to import the error class for certain modules first

Comment: You want `except turtle.TurtleGraphicsError:`

Comment: No at the top you may need to do something like `from pymysql import MySQLError`  that command is how you import the error class for pymysql

Comment: The string "black" should have worked as an argument for `turtle.bgcolor()`, is it possible you really tried to set it to "black\n", that is, took input from some config file and passed it to `turtle.bgcolor()` without first stripping it?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it correctly, the name TurtleGraphicsError is not defined in that scope. It is defined inside the turtle package (hence it tells you turtle.TurtleGraphicsError). You can either import it like:

```
from turtle import TurtleGraphicsError
```

or use it's actual name

```
import turtle
try:
    ...
except turtle.TurtleGraphicsError:
    print(...)
```